Minimal permutation degree of the dihedral group
Let $ D_n $ denote the Dihedral group of order $ 2n $. If $ p $ is prime then the minimal degree permutation representation of $ D_p $ is degree $ p $. If $ q $ is a prime power then I think the the minimal degree permutation representation of $ D_q $ is degree $ q $. For example, the minimal degree permutation representation of the group $ D_8 $ is of degree $ 8 $.
What about the case of general $ n $? My guess is that if $ n=\prod_{i} q_i $ where each $ q_i $ is a power of a distinct prime then the minimal degree is
$$
\text{degree}_{min}=\sum_i q_i 
$$
For example $ D_6 $ has a minimal degree permutation representation of degree $ 5 $. Is this guess correct?

This is correct if $n\geq 3$. To see this, note that if $D_n$ embeds in $S_m$ then $S_m$ must have an element of order $n$. If $n$ is the product of the $q_i$ then the only way to get an element of order $q_i$ in $S_m$ is a product of $q_i$-cycles, together with some cycles of length dividing $q_i$. Thus the smallest possibility is $q_i$ itself. Thus $m\geq \sum_i q_i$. But inside any symmetric group we always have an element $t$ of order $2$ inverting any product $x$ of cycles. (This is where $n\geq 3$ is needed. If $n=1$ then this statement fails, and if $n=2$ then $t=x$.) Thus the group $\langle x,t\rangle$ is isomorphic to $D_n$ whenever $x$ has order $n$, and so $m=\sum_i q_i$, as you claim.

Aren't $D_1 = S_2$ and $D_2 =  K_4$ problem cases here ?

Yes, sure. Thanks. I'll add $n\geq 3$.
